# Glassfish on Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am using Eclipse Luna on Mac Maverick.

1. I have downloaded GlassFish and extract it.
2. I have downloaded the Glassfish toolkit from the marketplace.
3. I am using Eclipse EE.
4. JAVA_HOME is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

When I try to define a new server, why isn't glassfish showing up as an option? What have I missed?

Comment: Did you install the `Oracle Java EE Tools` and the `Glassfish Tools`?

Comment: What do you mean? I have downloaded the Java 7 SDK from Oracle. And also the toolkit from marketspace.

Comment: These are the two packages you have to install to make it work but they should be included in what you call the Glassfish toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually Eclipse. JDK 7 only works with Eclipse EE in 64 bits version. So, basically if want to make glassfish an available server: you need to:

1. Use Eclipse EE 64 bits version
2. Use JDK-7
3. Make sure your JAVA_HOME is set/updated
   (In Mac, it usually sits under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/)
4. In Eclipse marketplace, download and install Glassfish-toolkit 
   (and restart the IDE of course)
5. Make sure your Eclipse EE/Project is using the correct JDK 
   (Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs)